# How to make a UIView that is aware of highlight?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I want to make a uiview that can be aware of highlight status, like a UILabel is when put inside a UICellTableView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass [`UIControl`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of `UIView`.

Comment: true, didn't thought of that since UILabel is not a UIControl